# How to update a value in the database in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a project using Python and Django in which I keeping track of all the products in my store, once I sell a particular product I need to update the number of units of that product remaining

Here is my Models.py file

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    prod_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.IntegerField()
    prod_type=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    units=models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return('Name:{0} Company: {1} Qty:{2} Price: {3} Type:{4} Units: {5}'.format(self.prod_name, self.company,self.quantity, self.price, self.prod_type, self.units))
```

Here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def display_product(request):
    items=Product.objects.all()
    context={
    'items':items
    }


    return render(request, 'index.html', context)   


def add_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form =ProductForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'add_new.html', {'form':form})


def edit_product(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'edit_product.html', {'form':form})  

def sell_product(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'sell_product.html', {'form':form})
```

Here is my sell_product.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
            <br>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class ="form-form row">
                <label for="UpdateSold">Units Sold</label>
                <input type="Units Sold" class="form-control" id="UpdateSold" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Units Sold">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Update Product</button>
        </form>         
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So here is a snippet of front end 
I have 25 Oreo cookies I sell 3 of them and I enter 3 in Units Sold so I want the Units value of Oreo cookies to be updated to 22[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLogy.jpg)

Comment: What is the issue or what are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony If I click on the sell button it redirects me to another page where I have to enter the number of units of a particular product that I have sold, now this input that I have given should change the value in my units field, but how do I link the input box in my sell_product.html file and my units field....I have already messed up the sell_product view which has been giving me errors but then I havent posted that piece of code here. Can you help?